# Learning Shell - creating a script with parameters that runs two separate cli apps

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, grep, youtube-dl

I want to learn shell script, so I'm trying to download a youtube video using youtube-dl then convert it to mp3 using ffmpeg.

I do it manually running `youtube-dl http://youtube.com/watch?v=...`
then
`ffmpeg -i downloadedFile -ab 256000 -ar 44100 audioFile.mp3`.

I know that I need to pass two arguments to my script, one for the video url and another for the audio file to keep things as simple as possible, but I don't know how to start. Maybe grep the video id in the url and using it to know which file to use to convert into mp3? (since youtube-dl saves the video named by it's id)

Can someone recommend me an article or documentation that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--output` parameter of youtube-dl to have an arbitrary template. Additionally, youtube-dl can already convert to mp3! Try

```
#!/bin/sh
youtube-dl -o '%(title)s.%(ext)s' -x --audio-format mp3 -- "$1"
```

- `-o` or `--output` defines the output name. You can use a number of templates, including `%(title)s` for the title of the video, `%(ext)s` for the extension, and `%(id)s` for the video ID. You can also use static filenames such as 'audio.%(ext)s`, which will result in an`audio.mp3` file.
- `-x` or `--extract-audio` advises youtube-dl to convert the video to an audio file (and remove the video file afterwards unless you pass `-k`). However, in contrast to your solution, youtube-dl will not recode audio streams that are already in mp3 - even with a relatively high bitrate such as 256k, you'll lose quality when you decode mp3 and re-encode it afterwards.
- If you want a specific bitrate, use the `--audio-quality` parameter, say `--audio-quality 256k`.
- The `--audio-format` parameter advises youtube-dl to convert audio to the given format. You can use `best` to always get the original audio (and not lose any quality), in whatever format it is.
- `"$1"` is the first parameter of your shell script. You can pass in whole URLs, video IDs, or some shortcuts (like `ytsearch:python` to search YouTube for "python" and pick the first video.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been voted `-1` - it solves the problem just fine, doesn't it? A comment on what part could be improved would be most helpful.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted the answer. Just tried it and works just fine! Thanks!
Why do the parameter needs to be within quotes?

Comment: Unquoted, `()` induces a subshell, so we must quote it in the output format. And since `$1` can contain spaces - like when you call the script with `ytsearch:stack overflow` - the quotes advise the shell to properly escape that as a single argument, and not as `youtube-dl ytsearch:stack   overflow`